# Guardar un file de un array() en laravel

Tags: laravel, array

tengo el siguiente resultado de un request de una vista:

```
array:10 [▼
  "_token" => "safbCVoGYiCk4cpDPJmSCZDJF17YkgAg21DwT7Iu"
  "tipopersona" => "2"
  "empresa" => "3"
  "persona" => "3"
  "tsolicitud" => "1"
  "comentario" => "Esto es un Comentario de Esta Solicitud"
  "carta_ministro" => UploadedFile {#601 ▶}
  5 => array:1 [▼
    0 => UploadedFile {#603 ▶}
  ]
  6 => array:1 [▶]
  7 => array:1 [▶]
]
```

Necesito guardar los últimos 3 array como archivos adjuntos`(file(array)->store('public'))` no se si es de esa forma. No se de que forma lo podría hacer, este request lo recibo en un controlador. Estos array son archivos adjuntos que se cargan desde la vista.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolvi, en el ajax donde cargaba los archivos que iba a subir, cambie el name por un dato de texto:

```
$('#doc_solicitud').append('<tr><td>'+docObj.documento_solicitud+'</td><td><input class="btn btn-default" type="file" name="doc'+docObj.id+'" id="doc'+docObj.id+'" required="true"></td></td></tr>');
```